# How to have an object key depend on another key in the same object?

Tags: javascript, enumerate

I have a very simple function that builds an object and logs it.

One of the keys in the object should be depending on another key.

I think it would be much clearer when I add the code

```
module.exports = function (information) {

    var numObj = {
        [-1]: "accepted",
        [0]: "fail",
        [1]: "success"
    }
    console.log(numObj)

    var ip = require('ip');
        var logObj = {
            UUID: information.UUID, // get from outside
            FN_TIME_STAMP: information.FN_TIME_STAMP, // not sure if necessary
            FN_CORRELATION_ID: information.FN_CORRELATION_ID,// get from outside
            FN_REF_ID: information.FN_REF_ID, //get from outside
            FN_METHOD_NAME: "docToMail", // constant
            FN_STATUS_CODE: information.FN_STATUS_CODE, //get from outside
            FN_STATUS_DESC: numObj[this.FN_STATUS_CODE], // depends on FN_STATUS_CODE
            FN_DOC_ID: information.FN_DOC_ID, //get from outside
            FN_USER_NAME: "", // empty for now, probably un-necessary
            FN_APP_ID: information.FN_APP_ID, //get from outside
            FN_RMT_ADDRS: ip.address(),//ip address of local machine
            FN_NUM_OF_RETRIES: information.FN_NUM_OF_RETRIES, // get from outside
            FN_FILETYPE: information.FN_FILETYPE, // get from outside
            FN_REC_STATE: numObj[this.FN_STATUS_CODE] //depends on FN_STATUS_CODE
        }
        console.log(logObj)
}
```

I just want FN_REC_STATE and FN_STATUS_DESC to be a string depending on FN_STATUS CODE.
If its -1 i want the string to be "accepted"
If its 0 i want the string to be "fail"
If its 1 i want the string to be "success"

as it as right now i just get undefined, please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `information.FN_STATUS_CODE` is either `-1`, `0` or `1`, the following solution should work.

If you change

```
FN_REC_STATE: numObj[this.FN_STATUS_CODE]
```

to

```
FN_REC_STATE: numObj[information.FN_STATUS_CODE]
```

then it should put the correct value into `FN_REC_STATE`.

This is because by the time that faulty line is evaluated, `this.FN_STATUS_CODE` hasn't been defined.

You should also change this for the definition of `FN_STATUS_DESC`.

Also, it looks like you may be misunderstanding what `this` refers to in the context of that function. It actually refers to the global object, rather than the `logObj` object.

Comment: Thank you! works perfectly. feels like I had a brain fart here. thanks again, i will mark as answer as soon as i can!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help. Sorry for the directness of the reply, I usually like to be much chirpier with smiley faces and stuff but often that's not appropriate for StackOverflow and I get told off haha. Good luck your code!